# Crossed synchronize blocks

Tags: java, multithreading

I have function that sends notification from `ThreadB` to thread `ThreadA` and waits notification from `ThreadA` back to `ThreadB`.

During period between `A` is notified by `B` and then `B` notified by `A` `ThreadA` reads `ThreadB` data and when finishes sends notification to `ThreadB`.

sendNotifyAndWaitNotify runs in ThreadB.

Tho synchronization one by one on the same object might look strange, but `B.sync.notify();` will send notification only when it exits synchronized block and if I will write everything in one block I will  wait firs and only when exit synchronized block it will do notification. That is not acceptable.

```
void sendNotifyAndWaitNotify() {
    synchronized(B.sync) {
        B.sync.notify();
    }
    //ThreadA reads ThreadB data
    synchronized (B.sync) {     
        try {
            debug("start waiting for notify");
            B.sync.wait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error( e.toString());
        }
    }
    debug("reader sleep done");
}
```

But this function is not correct, because ThreadA can read data and notify ThreadB at the moment when ThreadB is not started waiting. Is it possible to solve problem by crossing synchronization blocks like bellow:

```
void sendNotifyAndWaitNotify() 
   {
   synchronized(B.sync) // block #1
      {
      synchronized(B.sync)  // block #2
         {
         B.sync.notify();
         }

   //ThreadA reads ThreadB data

      try 
         {
         debug("start waiting for notify");
         B.sync.wait();
         } catch (Exception e) {
         error( e.toString());
         }
      debug("reader sleep done");
      }
   }
```

I expect that ThreadA will be waked up after exiting synchronization block #1 and not #2. And I expect that code in block #2 Maybe second block is better to make on different synchronization object?

I must use java 1.4.

Comment: are you required to use wait/notify?

Comment: I've edited your code to fix the formatting but maybe there seem to be some problems with it.  Can you rework and edit your text to explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Java 5 introduced many useful concurrency constructs... I'm sure one of them will solve the issue elegantly. It might be best to whiteboard the design with a question on Programmer's.

Comment: I must use java 1.4 and everything that is offered by this java version.

Answer (score 1):

You should always guard a call to `wait()` with a looped condition.

```
synchronized(B.sync){
    while(!myConditionIsSatisfied){
        B.sync.wait();
    }
    /* Do critical stuff */
}
```

That way if your condition is already satisfied by the time the thread arrives at the synchronization block, it won't wait for anything.

The other reason for guarding the wait with a looped condition is `wait()` is allowed by its contract to wake up *spuriously*. If that happens you want to send the thread back in to the `wait()` if your condition isn't satisfied.

See also: [JavaDoc for Object.wait(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) *Object.wait() is a call to Object.wait(0)*

Excerpt (emphasis mine):

> A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or
>   timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur
>   in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the
>   condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and
>   continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied. In other words,
>   **waits should always occur in loops**, like this one:
>
> ```
>  synchronized (obj) {
>      while (<condition does not hold>)
>          obj.wait(timeout);
>      ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Use two monitors, and boolean flags to indicate if the thread has to wait. That will protect you from spuriously wake-ups and you will not loose the notifications.

You can also just use one monitor, but in my opinion this is better readable.

If thread A calls notify on the monitor and thread B is not yet in wait state, the program will halt forever. So test if you have to wait.

```
public class Testnotify {

    private final Object monitorA = new Object();
    private boolean finishedA = false;

    private final Object monitorB = new Object();
    private boolean finishedB = false;

    private void threadAwaitAndNotify() throws InterruptedException {
        // do some stuff

        // notify the other thread that we are finished here
        synchronized (monitorA) {
            finishedA = true;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " Notify thread B.");
            monitorA.notifyAll();
        }

        // now wait for the other thread to finish
        synchronized (monitorB) {
            while (!finishedB) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " Waiting for thread B.");
                monitorB.wait();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " Thread B ready.");
        }
    }

    private void threadBwaitAndNotify() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitorA) {
            while (!finishedA) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " Waiting for thread A.");
                monitorA.wait();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " Thread A ready.");
        }

        synchronized (monitorB) {
            finishedB = true;
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " Notify thread A.");
            monitorB.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Testnotify testnotify = new Testnotify();

        final Thread threadA = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    testnotify.threadAwaitAndNotify();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }, "A");

        final Thread threadB = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    testnotify.threadBwaitAndNotify();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }, "B");

        threadA.start();
        threadB.start();

    }

}
```

Will give you the output:

```
B Waiting for thread A.
A Notify thread B.
A Waiting for thread B.
B Thread A ready.
B Notify thread A.
A Thread B ready.
```